# How secure is an airplane on the ground whilst passengers are boarding the aircraft?

Tags: safety, security, terrorism

On my recent flight to Ibiza, as I and the other passengers were boarding, there were many occasions where I could see right into the cockpit as the pilots and cabin crew were communicating back and forth for whatever pre-flight checks they were conducting. Being near the front of the queue at the gate, I was one of the first seated, the 10-20 minutes it took for the rest of the passengers to board was the time I refer to when I say I was able to see into the cockpit.

With it being my first flight in quite a few years, understandably I was extremely nervous. From the open cockpit to the smell of burning as the engines spooled up...

If we ignore terrorism, what is stopping a drunken passenger from, instead of turning right when they board at the front loading door, turn left and take a few steps into the cockpit, and if they were able to get into the cockpit, assuming they know absolutely nothing about the operation of a plane besides that pushing that pushing the throttles forward = more thrust = plane moves (faster), what damage could they do with a plane parked at a jetway or a plane parked out on the tarmac that requires a shuttle to drop passengers to the plane in order to board it.

If we introduce terrorism into the mix, what is stopping a group of strong men from forcing their way into the open cockpit past 1 or 2 cabin crew?

Comment: In my opinion much of the "security" is pure theater.  A lot of the security is there for psychological reasons...to make you feel secure.  I have no faith in the security theater we deal with as passengers, at least in the USA.

Comment: In your scenario, where the drunk turns into the cockpit during boarding & pushes up the throttles... nothing happens at all.  The engines aren't running while passengers are being boarded, and the starting process takes enough time that even if he hit the "start button" & then pushed the throttles forward, nothing much would happen then either.  Having the drunken passenger throw up on you is truly a greater risk than this particular scenario.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Aviation.SE.  I'm curious - "understandably I was extremely nervous" - it's not understandable to me, since I know that when I board a commercial flight, the safest part of my journey has just begun.  Why would you be "extremely nervous"?

Comment: To put this into perspective, the last passengers killed on a UK operated flight died in 1989.  Since then, approximately 36,000 people have been killed on the roads.  So, the understandable nervousness would be the car or taxi journey to the airport.

Comment: @Simon: Indeed, but fear is not rational, else everybody would love roller coaster and number 13, and vertigo wouldn't exist. And on the other hand, nobody would play at lottery either.

Comment: @Simon I dont think I'm alone when I say that flying can be a nerve racking experience. The thought in the back of my mind was that "something could go wrong".

Comment: @mins Thank you, I find it hard to believe that a person honestly couldn't understand why somebody would be nervous boarding and flying in an aircraft.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. How secure is the aircraft from what? What is stopping passengers from forcibly entering the cockpit and doing what? The aircraft is parked and the engines are not running. Any damage would become an insurance problem, not a security problem. Are you assuming that passengers would ask for a pushback, start the aircraft, taxi to the runway, and takeoff?

Comment: @Ksery I only asked out of genuine curiosity. I know the fear exists but that is very different to understanding why. I empathise with you and meant no disrespect, but it is genuinely not something I understand. My way of thinking about it is very simple. I am much safer in a plane than in a car, so much so that the maths is not worth doing. I am not nervous getting into a car, so why would I be nervous boarding a flight? I don't personally know anyone with any fear of flying, hence my curiosity. I wish there was something I could do to help you.

Comment: @mins Yes, but is the irrationality itself that I struggle with.  So, I love roller coasters, get really annoyed when people leave 13 off something, don't suffer from vertigo and don't play lotteries!  Blackjack, yes, but that's because with careful selections I can increase my odds beyond 50/50 ;)

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable, answerable question to me. Instead of getting all excited about the author's confession of nervousness, why not actually read, and try to answer, what is being asked? The question could be improved to make it a better question, but then so could many other, equally reasonable questions.

Comment: @DanieleProcida Well vote to re-open. I  happen to disagree with you, and it has nothing to  do with nervousness. What's to stop someone reaching in through my open car window and hitting me with a hammer?  What's to stop the driver of the train I will take on Thursday overriding the brakes and slamming into the station concourse?  What  stops the guy coming the other way round the corner on the wrong side of the road, slamming into me -  ad infinitum.  If there is a concrete answer, then it can be little more than "nothing".

Comment: @Simon I would vote to re-open it, if I could. But the questions are there, as asked, and clear, and answerable. If it's important for security in flight to have the cockpit doors locked, what's different about when the plane is on the ground? Presumably there is something different: what is it? How much damage could be caused by someone with momentary access to the controls of an airliner at such a time? If something prevents the possibility of thus causing serious harm or damage, what it is it?

Comment: @DanieleProcida Yes this is precisely what I was asking. What prevents someone from gaining access to the controls? Are there electronic locks in place preventing the fbw transmission of control inputs? What prevents somebody from accessing an empty plane etc? I wanted to completely reword my question but I thought it would be a bit strange to have all these comments beneath what would've essentially been a different but more precise question

Comment: I agree that this is an answerable question. The answer as to what's stopping them from causing the plane to move is the engines aren't running, wheels are chocked, etc. Not everyone knows that the engines are not running

Answer (score 4):

Those guys would gain no more than they'd gain if they hijacked the bus taking you to the airport.

If fact they'd gain less as they'd have nowhere to go and there's a lot more (armed) police at the airport to take them down than there is in some remote place they could drive that bus to.

The greatest risk to airliners isn't people forcing their way into the cockpit on the ground who are among the passengers waiting to board.
It's in the ground crew who can (at least in theory) bring aboard almost anything they wish (including bombs) with very little oversight (in fact this has happened in the past).
And there security has been seriously tightened (and it needed to be) over the decades, making that scenario far harder.
I won't say impossible, because nothing is impossible as long as there is a human factor involved anywhere in the chain, but bloody hard.

Comment: AFAIK, ground crew goes through security like everyone else - even security goes through security.

Comment: @Sanchises in theory yes, but that wasn't the case until quite recently. In practice, not so much. There are a lot of doors that simply open into secure areas using an employee pass. Not everyone has a pass that'll open it, but they exist. And vehicle gates (I've observed them) are often open with "known" cars and trucks just waved through. Heck, flocks of ramp workers are waved through when just holding up an employee pass (from a distance long enough the guard can't see anything except the colour, someone waving a coloured piece of cardboard could get through).

Answer (score 0):

It is a plane which transports passengers (>= 99% sane people) and a regular workplace for the crew, not a prison. If you are afraid of an open cockpit-door at ground, you should try to calm down and enjoy the journey. Life gives opportunities and risks. In my case I would always use the *opportunity* for a brief distant look at the cockpit and saying 'hello' to a pilot (if outside the cockpit and greeting passengers or chatting with the cabin crew), maybe even taking a picture if it is not disturbing.

Despite that, acpilot is right, security is mostly mere theatre.